# Features not within filter Encoding

Tags: filter, line, spatial, point, qgis

I was using following filter encoding establishing new WFS connection in QGIS i.e.
**https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/ows?version=1.1.0&typenames=gpw-v3:gpw-v3-coastlines&outputFormat=application/json&CQL_FILTER=dwithin(the_geom, POINT(37.696 14.964), 20, kilometers** so as
to select lines within 20km from above point coordinate.
[image]
Though the output is displayed however,line features seems to be far from the 20 km distance from the above point. Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is an old version of GeoServer which uses the units of the projection not the ones specified in the `DWITHIN` so you will need to use a projection that is in metres (EPSG:3035?).

Comment: @ Ian Turton...I changed the projection system to EPSG:3035 but also it isn't giving correct distance. Can't Within filter be used here. I tried using within filter but also its not giving any result. I need to use spatial filter encoding (except Bbox) for the line feature. I tried to use spatial filter dwithin to select lines from POINT(37.696 14.964) however its not working.What be the other solution?

Comment: It's hard to know, you would need to go back the the 2.10 manual to find out what was supported back then